# how to change value inside condition in for loops - Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

im new here. i just learn java, and i still confuse, how to change the variable inside for loop when the condition are true? here's the example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] candies = {1, 7, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1};
        List<Boolean> newArr = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        int firstGreat = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < candies.length; i++) {
            firstGreat = candies[0];
            if (candies[i] > firstGreat) {
                newArr.add(true);
                firstGreat = candies[i];
            } else {
                newArr.add(false);
            }
        }
   System.out.println(firstGreat);
    }
}
```

so i want change the firstGreat when condition are true.

Comment: wondering what you want to achieve with the snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close!

Take your line:

```
firstGreat = candies[0];
```

and place it before the for loop. Otherwise you keep resetting firstGreat to the first element every time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 1):

So, to change value inside condition for loops. Firstly, place `firstGreat = candies[0];` outside the for loop as we are assuming that first element of the candies array is the largest element.
Then, what we need to do is we have to iterate the entire candies array and we will compare `firstGreat` with every element of the candies array and if we find out that the `candies[i]` is greater than firstGreat than we will put value of candies[i] in firstGreat and this way we will get the greatest element.

```
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int[] candies = {1, 7, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1};
//List<Boolean> newArr = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
int firstGreat = candies[0];
for (int i = 0; i < candies.length; i++) {
    if (candies[i] > firstGreat) {
        //newArr.add(true);
        firstGreat = candies[i];
    } 
    //else {
        //newArr.add(false);
    }
}
System.out.println(firstGreat);
}}
```

Thankyou!!